# Problem with Boolean modifier-difference

Tags: modifiers, objects, workflow

I am modelling a PS4 where I need to make a hole in the console that resembles the PS4 logo. I have tried Boolean difference, it works for P and S but not for 4. Knife project also does not seem to work.

Is it a modelling issue? I am not able to figure it out.[image]
The logo and the console.

[image]
How it actually looks like, the P and S are only intersecting the mesh

Blend file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason boolean difference fails on the 4 is due to non-manifold geometry. You can select non-manifold geometry with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> in edit mode. In your case, this reveals an unconnected face on the extruded version of the 4 (likely due to an extra edge before extruding):

[image]

I added an extra edge ring and merged the corresponding faces:

[image]

And then the boolean succeeds.

[image]